# Multiplying a number with its reverse position starting from 2

Tags: oracle, loops, plsql

I have a small requirement.How to get the following output:

Input string is `123456`

I need to find the reverse position,starting from 2,i.e `234567`.
Now multiply each value with the reverse position value and add.
eg:`1*7+2*6+3*5+4*4+5*3+6*2` in plsql.

Comment: Is this another homework question

Comment: DECLARE
no NUMBER(20):='123456';
len NUMBER;
c VARCHAR2(40);
add varchar2(40);
total VARCHAR2(40):=0;
BEGIN
FOR i  IN 1..length(no)
LOOP
dbms_output.put_line('Looping '||i);
c:=substr(no,i,1);

dbms_output.put_line('The value of C is' ||c);

len:=length(no)+2;
len:=len-i;
dbms_output.put_line('Length  is '||len);
add:=c*len;
total:=total+add;
dbms_output.put_line('After multiplication'|| add);
dbms_output.put_line('Total is '||total);




END LOOP;
END;

Comment: is there any way to make it more efficient code?

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae2cc8/24)

**Query 1**:

```
WITH data ( value, total ) AS (
  SELECT 123456, 0 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_NUMBER( SUBSTR( value, 2 ) ),
         total + SUBSTR( value, 1, 1 ) * ( 1 + LENGTH( value ) )
  FROM   data
  WHERE  value IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT total FROM data WHERE value IS NULL
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae2cc8/24/0)**:

```
| TOTAL |
|-------|
|    77 |
```

Comment: Thanks,But i have tried the following way,is there any way to make it more effecient?                DECLARE
no NUMBER(20):='123456';
len NUMBER;
c VARCHAR2(40);
add varchar2(40);
total VARCHAR2(40):=0;
BEGIN
FOR i  IN 1..length(no)
LOOP
dbms_output.put_line('Looping '||i);
c:=substr(no,i,1);

dbms_output.put_line('The value of C is' ||c);

len:=length(no)+2;
len:=len-i;
dbms_output.put_line('Length  is '||len);
add:=c*len;
total:=total+add;
dbms_output.put_line('After multiplication'|| add);
dbms_output.put_line('Total is '||total);




END LOOP;
END;

Comment: @nkt. `SQL` is the most efficient way which is already answered above. Using `PLSQL` you already had solved it. Let us know if you need any special assistance.